# Displaying checked items in combobox using "combobox with checkbox"

Tags: c#, checkbox, combobox, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

I am building a windows store app and due to UI problems I have to implement checkbox inside combobox.I am stucked at following problem:I want to display the checked Item in "Combobox with Checkbox" .
What I want to do :
 http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/justguy/image_2827F1EB.png

```
     <ComboBox x:Name="cb2"            

                          DropDownOpened="cb2_DropDownOpened_1"         
                          DropDownClosed="cb2_DropDownClosed_1"
                          SelectionChanged="cb2_SelectionChanged_1"                              
                          Width="310" 
                          ItemsSource="{Binding Members}" 
                          DisplayMemberPath="{Binding Name}"
                          Height="50"  BorderBrush="#FF0A2562"
                           Tag="{Binding index}"

                          >


                        <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>

                            <CheckBox
                                   Background="Black"
                                   BorderBrush="Black"
                                Tag="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}"
                                Content="{Binding Name}"
                                IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsSelected,Mode=OneWay}"
                                Unchecked="CheckBox_Unchecked_1"
                                Click="CheckBox_Click"
                                />
                        </DataTemplate>

                    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>                      

                </ComboBox>
```

**Code Behind:**

```
private void CheckBox_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)sender;


        string k =(string) chk.Content;

        chkstr.Add(k);


    }
 private void CheckBox_Unchecked_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)sender;
        string k = (string)chk.Content;

        chkstr.Remove(k);
       // vl.selectedmembers.Remove(key);
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

In ComboBox Standard Template defined by Microsoft add a TextBlock in ContentPresenter.
Bind the Text Property of TextBlock with string.Now you can add the checked Items to string by converting the items to string explicitly.
@Patrick : ItemTemplate and ItemContainerStyle both will work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to retemplate the ComboBoxItem.  Specify ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle instead of ComboBox.ItemTemplate.  Inside of ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle, have a setter for Template.  Copy the default template and add a CheckBox.  Template-bind CheckBox.IsChecked to IsSelected, or animate IsChecked to true using an object animation in the Selected visual state.

Your approach won't work since IsSelected is a property on the ComboBoxItem container, not the data context.

Comment: Thanks for the Reply.But How to display the checked Items separated by comma in Combobox. Like this Image:[link](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/justguy/image_2827F1EB.png)